# Calculate Audio file duration

Tags: 7, views, files

I am using Drupal url field in which I input any external url of an MP3 file hosted on Twilio Server and I then use html5 audio tag to render it as an audio file in node display. Everything looks fine until my client asked me to calculate the duration of the audio and display it as a column in my views.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

getID3 can be used to calculate the size of the file.

```
$fileinfo = getID3_analyze(drupal_realpath($name2));
$playtime_sec = round($fileinfo['playtime_seconds'] / 60);

//Generate playtime in minutes (for display only), @type String
$playtime_mins = $fileinfo['playtime_string'];
```

use the following modules to integrate with views.
https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field
https://www.drupal.org/project/getid3

Comment: Its not basically a file, getID operates on a file but what I have is only url the file is hosted on remote server.

Comment: As per the code, i have posted you can specify remote path of the file to analyze the file attributes